# Busca automática de endereço do usuário

Tags: java, android

Algum método de busca automática de endereço a partir da localização atual do usuário? Sem precisar que o mesmo preencha os campos de endereço. Informando o CEP ou ao clicar um button de buscar endereço.

Comment: Use o gps do usuário

Answer (score 1):

Dê uma olhada na classe [Geocoder](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Geocoder.html) e seu método [getFromLocation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Geocoder.html#getFromLocation(double,%20double,%20int)).

Tem um [exemplo completo](https://developer.android.com/training/location/display-address.html) nos site para desenvolvedores do Android, mas, em resumo, é algo como:

```java
Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(this, Locale.getDefault());
List<Address> addresses = null;

try {
    addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(latitude, longitude, 1);
} catch (IOException ioException) {
    Log.e(TAG, "Serviço indisponível", ioException);
} catch (IllegalArgumentException illegalArgumentException) {
    Log.e(TAG, "Localização inválida", illegalArgumentException);
}

if(addresses != null && addresses.size() > 0) {
    Address address = addresses.get(0);
    // Esse é o endereço.
}
```

Para mais detalhes, e um exemplo funcional completo, recomendo a leitura [do guia](https://developer.android.com/training/location/display-address.html)

Comment: Por favor, se puder ser mais claro na sua resposta, pois somente este trecho de código não resolve o problema. Também indicar os guias para consulta fica mais caracterizado como comentário do que como resposta efetiva. Se possível colocar um código de autoria própria, para que fique entendida a solução como um todo.

Answer (score 1):

Bom, vou separar minha resposta em 2 partes:

- Realizar a busca quando o usuário inserir o CEP no campo de formulário:

`cep.setOnFocusChangeListener(OnFocusChangeListener { _, hasFocus ->
            if (!hasFocus) {
                if(Utils.validCep(cep.text.toString())){
                 //Request para o serviço de consulta do CEP
                }
            }
        })`

onde: o CEP é o meu `EditText`. Eu utilizei o método `OnFocusChangeListener` nesse caso porque do modo que montei meu formuário, era o mais adequado na minha visão. Mas você pode controlar via `IMEOptions` ou `TextChangedListener`, como preferir.

Vou deixar também a função que valida o CEP abaixo.

```
fun validCep(cep: String): Boolean {
        val pattern = Pattern.compile("^[0-9]{5}-[0-9]{3}$")
        val matcher = pattern.matcher(cep)
        return matcher.find()
    }
```

- Buscar dados do CEP inserido

Gosto de utilizar o [ViaCEP](https://viacep.com.br/) pra fazer isso.

Basta você enviar uma request para o endereço `viacep.com.br/ws/01001000/json/`, onde **01001000** seria o CEP a consultar, e ele te retorna um JSON nesse formato:

```
 {
  "cep": "01001-000",
  "logradouro": "Praça da Sé",
  "complemento": "lado ímpar",
  "bairro": "Sé",
  "localidade": "São Paulo",
  "uf": "SP",
  "unidade": "",
  "ibge": "3550308",
  "gia": "1004"
}
```

Basta você pegar o retorno e setar para os campos de endereço pro seu formulario em caso de retorno `200`.

Caso você não tenha um formulário para inserir o CEP, a melhor forma é seguindo a reposta utilizando o Geocoder, onde pegaria a localização do device para consulta.